# Quickparts don't work when using Record Center site template SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, quick-parts

The library columns don't pull through to Word when using the record center site template. Is there any way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set parserenabled property to true for your record ceneter
[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.parserenabled.aspx)

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://dev/records"
$web.parserenabled = $true
$web.update()
```